# Why endpoint does't response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have spring security config with in-memory saved users. There is any rules for users, one of them is sa\sa. There are couple controllers return Ok message if everything is okey(the endpoint is accessable) wher called get request by urls /test and /start
Spring-security protecs only /test endpoint
Spring-security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
  public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("sa")
        .password("{noop}sa")
        .roles("USER", "USER_ROLE")
        .and()
        .withUser("na")
        .password("na")
        .roles("USER", "USER_ROLE");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/test").hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER", "USER", "USER_ROLE")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
  }
  }
```

Yaml config:

```
  spring:
    datasource:
      username: user
      password: user
      driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    security:
      basic:
        enabled: true
```

So, when I send get request by postman to /start - it's return response ok, if try to call /test - there is no access.
I use postman like this:

[image]

So, the question is, why I can't to get reponse from /test endpoint(can't access to this url) ?

Error logs with rejection

> 2022-04-03 21:43:19.854 DEBUG 8872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request
> http://localhost:8080/test to session 2022-04-03 21:43:19.854 DEBUG
> 8872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     :
> Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access 2022-04-03
> 21:43:19.856 DEBUG 8872 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty
> SecurityContext 2022-04-03 21:43:19.857 DEBUG 8872 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not
> store empty SecurityContext 2022-04-03 21:43:19.857 DEBUG 8872 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request

Comment: What is your question, i dont understand

Comment: Have you enabled spring security debug logs and checked the reason for the 403?

Comment: @Toerktumlare added logs, there is rejection message

Comment: @Toerktumlare it already work when I full commented  ```configure(HttpSecurity http)```, but how I can apply spring-security only to any endpoints?

Comment: what you are asking is basic spring security, please google a tutorial or read the getting started section of the spring security reference documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing an authentication mechanism in your filter chain (e.g. `http.httpBasic()`. Note that the `spring.security.basic.enabled` property is not the correct way to enable HTTP Basic in the latest version(s) of Spring Security.

Take a look at the Hello Security sample's [SecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/hello-security-explicit/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java) and the [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html) section of the reference docs.